# HttpContext Class and its Thread Safety

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety, httpcontext

I have an **Singleton** object in application that has following property:

```
private AllocationActionsCollection AllocationActions
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["AllocationOptions.AllocationActions"] as AllocationActionsCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["AllocationOptions.AllocationActions"] = value;
    }
}
```

I'm dealing with one error (**HttpContext.Current.Session["AllocationOptions.AllocationActions"] is null** even though it is supposed to me always set to valid instance...). I just read in MSDN that **HttpContext** instance member are not guaranteed to be thread safe! I wonder if that could be the issue. There could be a resources race somewhere in application and the moment where **HttpContext.Current.Session["AllocationOptions.AllocationActions"] is null** is the moment where AllocationActions setter is used using this statement:

```
AllocationActions = new AllocationActionsCollection(Instance.CacheId);
```

My questions are:

a) I'm shocked that HttpContext.Current.Session is not thread safe. How to safely use that property then?
b) do you have any ideas why that Session variable can be null (even though I'm pretty sure I'm setting it before it's used for the first time)?

Thanks,Pawel

EDIT 1:

a) line that initializes session variable is set every 2 minutes with following statement (executed in Page_Load)

```
AllocationActions = new AllocationActionsCollection(Instance.CacheId);
```

b) code that calls getter is called in event handlers (like Button_Click)

c) there is not custom threading in application. only common HTTP Handler

Comment: OK, so what is calling this code?  Is this an explicit threading situation ( calling Thread.Start) or by threading is this a web service, or HTTP handler, or what?

Comment: When do you execute code that returns null session? In page constructor Session IS null; In Page_Init or Page_Load Session IS NOT null

Comment: you need to show more source code - esp. where this is set and clarify the threading situation... if for example you access HttpContext.Current outside an IIS thread (i.e. in a thread you started separately) while being hosted in IIS this would yield "interesting" results...

Comment: What the docs mean is that a particular HttpContext instance may only be safely used from one thread at a time. This is desired behaviour because it is tied to the thread that is processing the page request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **singleton** object is realized by restricting the instantiation of a class to one object.

`HttpContext.Current.Session` is an area dedicated to a single user; any object stored in Session will be available only for the user/session that created it.

Any object stored in `Application` will be available only for every user/session.

Any **static object** also, will be available only for every user/session. [Suggested implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) always use static objects.. why didn't you?

Comment: Thanks, for I moment I got confused. Of course it turned out that there was a bug in application where Session variable wasn't set...

Answer (score 2):

To access the session property safely you would just wrap the access in a lock statement and use the SyncRoot object of the session class.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpContext.Current` returns a separate `HttpContext` instance for each request. There can be multiple threads processing requests, but each request will get its own `HttpContext` instance. So any given instance is not being *used* by multiple threads, and thread safety is not an issue.

So unless you're manually spinning up multiple threads of your own for a single request, you *are* threadsafe.

Comment: This is not true. IIS will spin off new threads when certain loads are reached and if you're storing configuration information or something in a static variable, that data won't be reachable from the new thread.

Comment: @DonRolling, got a citation for that? I've never heard of IIS starting more than one thread for the same request, and I'm not sure what that would even mean.

Comment: I don't have a citation, but the issue has happened to me. It doesn't happen during a single request. It happens if you're storing something like db config values in a static variable. If IIS begins a new thread due to traffic, then those config values weren't available to the new thread.

Comment: @DonRolling, you're confusing threads with appdomains. Statics are shared across all threads within an appdomain, so those values *will* be available to the new thread. It's only if it spins up a new appdomain that you'd get a new copy of the static variable. And even then, your init code should still run and initialize the variable, just like it did in the first appdomain.

Comment: Further discussion of how ASP.NET migrates HttpContext between threads here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109526

Comment: @JoeWhite - `it's a static member. So it's threadsafe` - Why are you implying that because it is a static member it is thread safe? My understanding is a static member is shared across all instances.

Comment: @variable You know, I have no idea what point 11-year-ago me was trying to make with that sentence. I trimmed my answer to be more to-the-point and hopefully clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The thread safety of the `HttpContext` class is pretty standard for .NET. The basic rule of the thumb (unless explicitly specified) is that static members are thread safe and instance members aren't.

In any case it is hard to tell why your session variable is null without looking more into the code that sets/resets it. Or perhaps you are calling your `get_AllocationActions` method from a different session than the one you set it in. Again, more code would help.