# How to access Application State in a thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

I am using a threading architecture in my ASP.NET web application. In this application, I have maintained  a global application variable that i want to access in a Thread.

How can i get Application state in a Thread?

Comment: Try Passing the Application object in the other thread.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpContext.Current` will be null in subsequent threads. See this question for details:
[The cross-thread usage of "HttpContext.Current" property and related things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109526/the-cross-thread-usage-of-httpcontext-current-property-and-related-things/12141601)

However, you could just pass `System.Web.HttpContext` to the threads and access `Current` from each thread.